# jQuery + Clock & Weather

Tags: jquery, time, weather

Is there a jQuery plugin which would take an input of a country and return my the the time and weather status at that moment?

Comment: why do you nead especially jquery plugin for this ?

Comment: +1 for jQuery! Have you tried `$("New York").weather()`?

Comment: Its not necessary, but since I am already using jQuery thought that would be helpful, if there is an alternative, I can explore it.

Comment: I don't this is completely dependent on jQuery. You would need a server side piece like a service etc that would actually return the data (time/weather etc) and then jQuery could be used to display the results.

Comment: hmm, are there any scripts if I send the country name which would return the data that I want?

Comment: Hmz, have you tried coding anything yet ?

Comment: @Khez, yes I did try something but was not successful.

Comment: Post it then :) I'll give you an example of code that works with your requests after.

Comment: @Jakub, that's exactly what I tried and I didn't get it.

Comment: Even if I could get $("Cambridge").weather() to work I have another issue with this, Cambridge is is in a lot of countries, US, UK and in a lot of states in the US, so I should be able to specify something like what jDigiClock has done with the Location database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one does a whole widget - maybe you could modify it to just return as text if that is what you need: http://www.radoslavdimov.com/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-digiclock/

Comment: I have checked that, but internally its using setting from http://www.radoslavdimov.com/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-digiclock/WeatherLocationDatabase.txt, and I don't want a widget, just the datetime/weather

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a web service to return those data. 
Google can provide that information:
http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=Buenos%20Aires

but you'll need a server side script to connect to the web service (like explained in the @billy-moon's second link).